# Calling an asynchronous closure from a delegate's source ViewController

Tags: swift, asynchronous, delegates, closures

I have the following setup :

[image: Storyboard.main]

1. **Launch VC** performs an asynchronous API request in a closure `dataGatheringClosure`
2. The `dataGatheringClosure` closure's completion handler passes the result to **VC1** via delegation using protocol method `setData`.
3. Within `setData`, **VC1** passes the result to **VC2** using the following code:

   ```
   if let vc2 = self.tabBarController?.viewControllers?[1] as? VC2Controller {
       vc2.data = result
   }
   ```

I'm able to transfer data from the **Launch VC** to **VC2**, but now I need to refresh the data by performing the `dataGatheringClosure` in **Launch VC**.

My question is: How do I access **Launch VC**'s methods from **VC2**? And is this approach sound?

As a workaround, I copied the `dataGatheringClosure` closure code inside **TabBar VC** and had **VC 2** call its `self.tabBarController.dataGatheringClosure` method. However, it is duplicative, and also I don't know if it's best practice to execute heavy API requests within a `TabBarController`.

Comment: have look this repo simply show how to transfer data back and forth in viewcontrollers https://github.com/shauket/DataViewController

Answer (score 0):

The first step is to separate the data from the ViewControllers. Create a singleton class like below and use it to pass around the data you need.

```
class Data {

    static let shared = Data()
    // Declare any other data properties you need here...
    var result = [String]()

    private init() {}

    func initialize() {
        // Write code to initialize the data
        refresh()
    }

    func refresh() {
        // Write code to refresh the data
    }
}
```

Initialize data at app startup or wherever required using the below code:

```
Data.shared.initialize()
```

You can now access data from anywhere within your app using the static variable Data.shared. To refresh data you can do the following:

```
Data.shared.refresh()
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: have a look at this question https://stackoverflow.com/q/137975/2299040

Comment: @SahilManchanda if I avoid using a singleton, what alternative ways are there to communicate back and forth between my controllers?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/5210535/2299040 this will give you a great direction :)

Comment: Delegate and singleton are both great choices. When using singleton just make sure you free the memory when you no longer need them. Just set Data.shared = nil. The declaration should change to: static let shared: Data! = Data(). Use them as you see fit for your current situation.

Comment: In one of my apps, I used singleton and it worked great for doing an async refresh on the data whenever the app received a notification from iCloud. In my case, many ViewControllers share the same data (for the lifecycle of the application) and it served the purpose.